# Springboot actuator refresh and bus-refresh always return 401 Unauthorized

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I am hitting `bus-refresh` endpoint from my Jenkins and i wanted that endpoint to be secure-free.

Below is my application.yml

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,refresh,bus-refresh
      base-path: /
  health:
    ldap:
      enabled: false
```

Below is my http-configuration in spring-boot

```java
http
                    .anonymous()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html", "/error", "/swagger-resources/**", "/webjars/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/test/**", "/api/v1/calculate/**").permitAll()

                    .antMatchers("/health", "/refresh/", "/bus-refresh/").permitAll()

                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer()
```

Now when i hit `curl --request GET http://localhost:8080/health` i get proper response like below

`{"status":"UP"}`

but when i hit `curl --request POST http://localhost:8080/bus-refresh`

or `curl --request POST http://localhost:8080/refresh`

i get 403 and 401

`{"timestamp":"2020-08-26T10:46:26.370+00:00","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"","path":"/bus-refresh"}`

I tried all that i can, but still am unable to bring both `refresh` and `bus-refresh` out of security. Need help

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm having this same issue and I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: nope.. i rather had the endpoint protected and made my pipeline to fetch bearer-token every time it hits the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

I'm asking this just in case because I didn't see it in your example. In your configuration you have:

```
http
...
.antMatchers("/health", "/refresh/", "/bus-refresh/").permitAll()
...
```

In the health endpoint you didn't set the trailing slash, so when you invoke `curl --request GET http://localhost:8080/health` you get a proper response like you said. But then you invoked `refresh` and `bus-refresh` without the trailing slash and both endpoints were defined with it. Did you try to curl those endpoints like there were defined in your http configuration? (with trailing slash)

Hope it helps, let me know if it works.